# How to find the two combinations of elements that are present the most in all the groups?

Tags: sql

For example in this simple table:

| Group | Element |
| --- | --- |
| xxx | a |
| xxx | b |
| xxx | c |
| xxx | d |
| xxx | e |
| yyy | a |
| yyy | b |
| yyy | f |
| yyy | g |
| zzz | a |
| zzz | b |
| zzz | c |
| zzz | g |

'a' and 'b' are the combination of elements present the most in all groups

Comment: What's your question, exactly? Can you tag the specific RDBMS you're working with (answers may materially vary between each)? Can you provide the query you've already written in an attempt to meet the requirement you've described in accordance with our [ask] guidance?

Comment: Sample data is great, but you also need to _specify_ the expected result. And show us your current query attempt. I.e. a [mcve].

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: I'm using PostgreSQL although I am more interested in the logic to solve the puzzle (unless a specific feature is needed). The expected result should be the two elements. I am still attempting to create a possible solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it with a triangle join

```
with c1 as (
  select t1.grp, t1.Element e1, t2.Element e2
  from tbl t1
  join tbl t2 on t1.grp = t2.grp and t1.Element < t2.Element 
)
  select e1,e2
  from c1
  group by e1,e2
  order by count(*) desc
  limit 1
```

Comment: thank you for your answer. I am confused at the join with t1.Element < t2.Element. I just learned that the operator can be used with two strings and would check the alphabetical order of the fields. Could you explain me what happens/why we use it in this case?

Comment: This is known as a "triangle join". We need only pairs where elements are different and for a pair {a,b}  we take only one turple, (a,b) here. You can as well use > to take (b,a) instead.